# Check for a specific string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a custom div that's changed to an input element, this custom div input element has a `<p>` tag inside with a default placeholder text. I want to check it is not empty like doing it in a required property in a normal input element.

When submitting I want JavaScript to check whether the div element has the default place holder or new text.

I used this code

```
var data =$('#divtext').html();
if(data == '<p>Default place holder</p>')
{
     console.log('empty');
}
else
{
     console.log('notempty');
}
```

However no matter how I submit the div with no text I get the 'notempty' response but why?

Comment: So what is `data` equal to in that case?

Comment: `$('divtext')` would select elements with **tag name** "divtext". There is no such element in HTML. Learn more about selectors: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/, http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/.

Comment: @FelixKling that was a typing mistake

Comment: I think you should undo your edit. Correcting your code makes it unclear what your question was to anyone viewing this question in the future, since there is no problem in the code anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is very simply that your selector is wrong. You need to select classes via:

```
var data = $('.divtext').html();
```

and ids via:

```
var data = $('#divtext').html();
```

Also, you should watch out with checking for contents via string comparison. It'd be much better to search for a keyword, such as the word "Default", by doing the following:

```
var $data = $('#divtext p').html(); //notice I retrieve the html contents of the contained <p>, not the parent <div>.
if ($data && $data.trim().toLowerCase().indexOf('default') === 0) {
    console.log('empty');
} else {
    console.log('notempty');
}
```

That will make it much more likely that you'll indeed match what you want. The `.trim().toLowerCase()` prevents whitespace and casing from breaking it.

Comment: yah my mistake :) thanks for the additional help

Answer (score 3):

Your selector is not correct.

Do you have an element with the id divtest? If so you need:

```
var data = $("#divtext").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't include any selector,

if your div with class

```
var data = $('.divtext').html();
```

if your div with id

```
var data = $('#divtext').html();
```